# How to store div data in Mysql db?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datastore

I am new in PHP. I have a code in which i use multiple Inline Text Editor. For refrence i have a link [JQuery Widgets Inline Text Editor](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxeditor/index.htm#demos/jqxeditor/javascript-editor-inline-editing.htm)
For every Text editor i use multiple divs. Now i want to store my div data in Mysql db. But i dont now How to get a div data in a variable? I just need help of syntax how i store a div data in mysql db

Here Is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>Notification Letter.</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="image/pacra_logo.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcolorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editor1').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });            
        $('#editor2').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });            
        $('#editor3').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });            
        $('#editor4').jqxEditor({ 
        });                 
        $('#editor5').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });
        $('#editor6').jqxEditor({ 
        });
        $('#editor7').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });
        $('#editor8').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });
        $('#editor9').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });
        $('#editor10').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
        });
        $('#editor11').jqxEditor({
        });
    });
</script>
<div style="width: 30%; float:" contenteditable="true" id="editor1">
    <p> NL FY 15-147 (PSO-040515) </p>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px; text-align:justify; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" id="editor6">
    <p>This has reference to our communication and discussion with you and your team regarding rating of Pakistan State Oil Company Limited (PSO). We appreciate that PSO management has been forthcoming in providing all the requisite information. This has enabled PACRA in forming the right ration opinion.</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Which Tag You Wanna Store In DB?

Comment: I use Div tag. and in div i use Text Editor. Now i want to store Data which is in texteditor

Comment: Can You Get The Text Editor Data Using Javascript? If You Can Use The Answer That I'm Going To Post To Send The Data To A PHP File

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian Please post the answer

Comment: you can use ajax to post the contents to a php page from there you can store it to db. You can obtain the div values by usnig jquery div selector or with the id of that particular div

Comment: @HarigovindR can u tell me the syntax how to get div values by div id?

Comment: @sunny inside your jquery you can do this $('#divId').text(). Refer jquery documentation for more details i will post the link in the next comment

Comment: @sunny [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) , [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) , [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/). Refer these three links

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title id='Description'>Notification Letter.</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="image/pacra_logo.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcolorpicker.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxeditor.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#editor1').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });            
                $('#editor2').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });            
                $('#editor3').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });            
                $('#editor4').jqxEditor({ 
                });                 
                $('#editor5').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });
                $('#editor6').jqxEditor({ 
                });
                $('#editor7').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });
                $('#editor8').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });
                $('#editor9').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });
                $('#editor10').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
                });
                $('#editor11').jqxEditor({
                });
            });
        </script>
    <script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
              url: "process.php", 
              data:{data:$("#editor6").html()},
              success: function(result){
            alert("success");
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>
    </script>
        <div style="width: 30%; float:" contenteditable="true" id="editor1">
            <p> NL FY 15-147 (PSO-040515) </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px; text-align:justify; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" id="editor6">
            <p>This has reference to our communication and discussion with you and your team regarding rating of Pakistan State Oil Company Limited (PSO). We appreciate that PSO management has been forthcoming in providing all the requisite information. This has enabled PACRA in forming the right ration opinion.</p> 
        </div>
```

Save this

Comment: In my scenario i think i can only use Div. Coz i divide my page with muitiple divs.

Comment: Then you can use jquery and ajax normal http request wont work

Comment: Can u please write syntax for me?

Comment: @sunny Instead of asking for syntax please refer google and try out codes please. You got the basic logic right thats why we are here

Comment: @DhinjuDivakaran and Now what m doing in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You Should Write A jQuery AJAX To Send Data To A PHP File(Considering That You Can Get The Text With Javascript/jQuery):

**jQuery**

```
// put this in your <Script> in $(document).ready(... section

// This Line Gets The Text Of The Editor 
var textVariable = $("#editor6 p").text();

// This Part Sends The Data To The Defined PHP File And Returns The Result
$.post("TARGET_PHP_FILE.php", {TypedText: textVariable}, function(data, status){
    // Do Something With The Response
    // data: every thing that prints on php file
    // status: HTTP Response Code
    // For more Info: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp
});
```

**PHP**

```
// Your Text Is Available Like This:
$text = $_POST['TypedText'];

// Then You Can Store It In Database Like This:
if ($db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass)) {
    // Connected to the server
    if ($select = mysqli_select_db($db, "DATABASE_NAME")) {
        // Selected the database
        $query = "Your Query";
        if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
            // Query sent
            if (mysqli_affected_rows($db)) {
                echo "Done";

                mysqli_close($db);
            }else{
                echo "Fail";

                mysqli_close($db);
            }
        }else{
            echo "Query Not Sent";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Selection Failed";
    }
}else{
    echo "Connection Failed";
}
```

Comment: Sir I am new in PHP. I cant understand Jquery Deeply . Please could you write an explain code?

Comment: Yes i need more. the thing you write in comment. i dont able to write code of it. Actually i need to store my data in my db

Comment: Could You Please Be More Percise? Which Part Should I Explain?

Comment: please explain this // Do Something With The Response
    // data: every thing that prints on php file
    // status: HTTP Response Code.................. what i can do write here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82668/discussion-between-hossein-maktoobian-and-sunny).